# How to do coVerifyOrder of livedata.postValue(any()) - It is returning io.mockk.MockKException: Failed matching mocking signature for

Tags: kotlin, mockito, android-livedata, mockk

Scenario - 
Hi I am new in testing using mockk. I want to test the order in which methods are being called in viewmodel. And I want to test `livedata.postValue` in `verify` block{} but mockk is giving an **exception**. Kindly also help me to understand the meaing of exception

**MyViewModel.kt**

```
fun doWork(showError: Boolean = false) {
    launch {
        val result = getImageUseCase.getImages()
        if (!showError) {
            withContext(uiDispatcher) {
                liveDataResponse.postValue(LiveDataResult.success(Response(result)))
            }
        } else {
            throw Exception("Unknown")
        }
    }
}
```

**MyViewModelTest.kt**

```
@Test
fun verifyOrderOfMethodExecution(){

    coEvery { getImageUseCase.getImages() } returns 1
    myViewModel.doWork()
    coVerifyOrder {
        getImageUseCase.getImages()
        myViewModel.liveDataResponse.postValue(any())
    }
}
```

Exception -

```
io.mockk.MockKException: Failed matching mocking signature for
SignedCall(retValue=, isRetValueMock=true, retType=class kotlin.Any, self=GetImageUseCase(usecase#1), method=getImages(Continuation), args=[Continuation at com.rahullohra.lab.MyViewModelTest$verifyOrderOfMethodExecution$2.invokeSuspend(MyViewModelTest.kt:79)], invocationStr=GetImageUseCase(usecase#1).getImages(continuation {}))
left matchers: [any()]
```